# Left Join issues

Tags: php, laravel-4, query-builder

```
$orders = Order::where('status','=',2)
            ->with(array(
                'orderItems' => function($query) {
                    $query->whereNull('status');
                }
            ))->leftjoin('users', function($join)
   {
        $join->on('orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
   })
            ->get();
```

When i do a left join , i can retrieve the user's details but the Order Number will become User_ID(Order Table)
eg when i try to get ->User_Id or ->Order_Id it will be the same which doesnt make sense because how can a order id duplicate like a user id.

user :: has many orders

This only happens on left join / join, any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: You should make the users & orders a 'relationship' - then you dont need the join in the first place. See the L4 docs about relationships.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define it as a relationship:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
}

class Order extends Eloquent {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Then do

```
$orders = Order::where('status','=',2)->with(array(
            'orderItems' => function($query) {
                $query->whereNull('status');
            }
        ));
echo 'this order belongs to user_id: '.$orders->user()->id;
```

Comment: I get like Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::User()  isit because i need to use ; something?

Comment: Sorry - i fixed my code slightly. Basically you need the "belongsTo('User') to be the same name as your "user" model.

Comment: The echo doesnt work, someone told me i cant use user() like this in a relationship anyway i did this in blade and it worked {{$order->user->first_name}} THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have the rep for a comment. Previous code sample has the wrong function names (says comments in both cases)?

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Order');
    }
}

class Order extends Eloquent {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the tables are merged together and returned as a single table. For example, `orders.id` and `users.id` will be in conflict for the value `id` of the table.

To fix it is really simple actually: simply add `->select('tablename.*')` to the function. Of course, if you need more lines, make sure to specify them.

In your case:

```
$orders = Order::where('status','=',2)
            ->with(array(
                'orderItems' => function($query){
                    $query->whereNull('status');
                }
            ))
            ->leftjoin('users', function($join){
                $join->on('orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
            })
            ->select('orders.*')
            ->get();
```